# JSP Error 404 on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: java, jsp, google-chrome, firefox, tomcat8

I'm working on a java project (servlet, jsp...) with tomcat.
When I use the url http://localhost:8080/nameHere/ i have the following error :

Not Found
The requested URL /nameHere/ was not found on this server.

I have it with Firefox and Chrome it works with IE and eclipse web browser.
I uninstall firefox several times, same with chrome but nothing happened.
A day it worked everywhere and the day just after (with no change between) it doesn't ...

Any idea ?

Comment: It's probably running on another port or there is nothing deployed at nameHere. This is never a browser issue however.

Comment: it work in IE but not in chrome?

Comment: wow .. works in IE but not in chrome.. Exceptional

Comment: have you tried in [incognito](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/OsmsL2-_EP8)

Comment: problem can be in jsp pages which have some code which not supported by chrome

Comment: Same problem here. Using Netbeans, the run button launches the project in IE. It runs there, a bit buggy but still, it can find pages. I copy and paste the same code in Chrome and 404 error. If it were an issue with mapping, why is it running in IE? I am not using any kind of proxy either. 
How strange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem on firefox. It was the company's proxy. It was configure but when I delete all and I set the same configuration it works.

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing your servlet/jsp mapping. I would look at your web.xml (or however you are configuring the mapping) to make sure that you have a servlet/jsp mapped at that name.

Comment: in my web.xml i have only that : `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>nameHere</display-name>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>`

Comment: I think this configuration is incorrect. You need to map your servlet/jsp name (in your case nameHere) to the jsp/servlet that will serve your response. You with me?

Comment: I post an answer, the problem was my proxy (don't know why but delete the configuration and add the same solve my problem)